# Term OR word for specific type of a SQL table

Tags: terminology, sql

I am looking for a `Term`/`Word` for specific type of tables.

I have tried to search a lot, but I could not come up with best search terms for this.

Tables that hold some master information, such as products, users, customers, brands etc. for the system are called - `Master tables`.

Tables that hold some transaction information, such as orders, deliveries, invoices etc. are called - `Transaction tables`.

Tables that hold cross join (many to many relationship) information - are called `Third tables` OR `Link Tables`.

Now, the tables I am looking the term for; stores the information for a specific time period. So, for example past 12 months data only. When a month is lapsed the last month data is wiped out and the current month data would start stacking up. Once the current month is lapsed again the 12th month data would be wiped out, making space for latest month data.

The best I have come up with is `Rolling Entry Tables`, but I want to know if there already exists a common terminology for this.

Comment: Can I know the reason for the downvote?

Comment: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6583/31260)

Comment: "Archive tables" or "history tables."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a formal name for those sorts of tables. Data is normally cleared down to aid performance although (in the UK at least) you sometimes need to keep *N* years' worth for auditing purposes.

If you have a data store in one database and have a highly performant database with a subset of the that data store for application or reporting purposes, this is a [mart/repository type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart) scenario.

There is the concept of a [sliding window](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/partitioning-in-sql-server-managing-sliding-window-scenario.html) but this really relates to large partitioned tables where you might only have the capacity to store a given amount of data and you either delete or hive off the rest.

Answer (score 2):

**In layman term's:**

- Those tables are called **historical tables, history tables or audit tables**.
- The fact that you have a 12-month retention policy doesn't make them into a different type of table.
- The deletion (or not) of old historical data is part of the normal life-cycle of data.

Comment: Audit tables typically store which users have accessed various parts of the system. They have nothing to do with retention periods AFAIK...